# Curl_exec return null in php

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem to get the data using curl operation. Here i hide the token, If i use the url only in my browser then it returns the data but here its null.

```
<?php 
$token = "TOKEN"; //the actual token hidden
$url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/getRecords?authtoken=".$token."&scope=crmapi";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result; //does not return anything
?>
```

Where i do mistake please help me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how you can try with `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` which is used to return the output and `curl_errno()` to track the errors :

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/my_url.php" ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$postResult = curl_exec($ch); 

if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
   print curl_error($ch); 
} 
curl_close($ch);
```

Helpful Links: [curl_errno()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php), [curl_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: After i use this code i get: 
    "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Comment: It return some o my all data, It return only the numbers not the stirngs.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines:

```
<?php 
$token = "TOKEN"; //the actual token hidden
$url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/getRecords";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("authtoken"=>$token,"scope"=>"crmapi"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result; //does not return anything
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please see below article , not just turn off verify , you should update your php.ini with pem file

https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/

Anyone running a recent Linux distribution is probably already OK, because they get the curl libraries bundled in through their package managers and recent curl libraries come with the latest CA root certificate bundle from Mozilla.org.

For a PHP installation that doesn’t come with this file, like the Windows PHP distribution, you need to download the CA root certificate bundle and tell PHP where to find it.