# Curl returns NULL only

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem in curl for one specific server. I have a service api and its working fine from other servers but on this specific one i am having issue. Code i tried is as below :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$url = 'http://services.exportfeed.com/test.php';
$postfields = array(
    'fetch'   => '1',
    'country' => 'US',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    print_r($error_message);exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($result);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

While hitting the url it just returns null, no error no warning nothing. When i curl from terminal it returns the message it should return.

Can anyone help me solving this issue. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203753/curl-exec-return-null-in-php) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324819/php-curl-returns-nothing) guide but this did not solve. 
My hosting said like this [image: reply from host]

I am stuck in this. Please help.

Comment: What does `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2);` do? Is `2` a valid value there? `json_decode($var)` can produce null if you don't pass it valid json. I would check the output before attempting to decode.

Comment: why `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);` if you hav just **http** url ?

Comment: I tried your code, it worked perfectly.

Comment: [`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) should be a boolean (`true` or `false`). Setting to `2` is meaningless (it _is_ meaningful to `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` however).

Comment: var dump the result before passing it through json_encode. Json encode only supports utf8 chars and will return false if it fails

Comment: @Alex I i don't put value 2 then it curl will provide me warning saying value 1 cannot be used , use value 2 instead.

Comment: @Ibu I have only return json_encode(array('message'=>'curl test','status'=>true)) from the curl url server. So utf8 chars would not be a problem I guess. Any other guesses

Comment: @Alex I have tried CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1,0 , true,false, 2 all. Every try gave me the same result.

Comment: I ran your code as is on the command line and browser and it worked. where are you running this code?

Comment: @Ibu Yes the code is executing okay on my other servers too. One of my clients server is giving me this issue. He says he has TLS in his server. Would that cause any problem in performing curl without handshaking ?